# How to manage duplicate dependencies in subcharts in a Helm Umbrella Chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a Helm Umbrella Chart that I'm trying to write which has dependencies on 2 charts (for simplicity's sake). Chart A and Chart B. Both Chart A and Chart B have defined dependencies on Chart C. When I'm writing the Umbrella chart I specify a dependency on Chart A and B. When I try to install my Umbrella chart I get an error:

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: serviceaccounts "chart-c" already exists

My guess is this is happening because both Chart A and Chart B are trying to install the Chart C app. How do I manage these dependencies in my Umbrella Chart?

Comment: My understanding is that, if the umbrella chart depends on A and B and then A and B both depend on C, Helm's usual behavior is to install C only once, all as part of the same release.  Have you separately installed any of these charts?  In the charts' object naming, do you include the Helm `{{ .Release.Name }}` or use a helper template that includes it for you?

Comment: I have not separately installed any of the charts. In the charts name I am not using `{{ .Release.Name }} it's just hard coded (in this case mysql).

Comment: While there's going to be a lot of detail in the chart, can you try to edit the question to include a [mcve]?  It's a little hard to tell where the duplicate service account might come from.  Locally you might try running `helm template` on the parent chart, which will write out the rendered YAML, and might give you some hints as to where the duplicate service account comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to use `helm template` - When doing that I certainly see 2 serviceaccounts for mysql both named `release-name-mysql`. I'm not sure if this is the write solution but what I did was to add if blocks around the duplicate objects, and then just turn the duplicates off in my umbrella values file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with `alias`.
Example: In the dependencies section of the `Chart.yaml` file.

```
dependencies:
  - name: mongodb
    version: 12.1.2
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    alias: mongodb
    condition: mongodb.enabled
  - name: mongodb
    version: 12.1.2
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    alias: mongodb-tracing
    condition: mongodb-tracing.enabled
```

You can read more about alias [here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#alias-field-in-dependencies)